# Using a remote MacBook for building React Native apps with XCode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-windows

I have a Windows-machine and would like to use React Native for developing cross-platform UWP (so no Expo) and iOS apps. I also have a MacBook that I would like to use as a build host, like you can do with Xamarin.

Can remote build and iOS simulation with XCode be done using React Native and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to turn your Mac in a build server. If you need the simulator you could use a screen sharing program like VNC.